# If there was no quantum entanglement, what would change?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement

I understand entanglement is a phenomenon that is rather difficult to control or observe and I have read many times that it does not concern with macroscopic things.

On the other hand, I read that photosynthesis would depend on it.

In general, if quantum entanglement did not exist would that change a lot of things in the world as we know it?

I am just trying to figure if this is something actually pervasive or more of a side note, a curiosity.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121165/discussion-on-question-by-exocytosis-if-there-was-no-quantum-entanglement-what).

Comment: Just as a friendly suggestion, I suspect a way you can ask your question in a way that makes sense more to physicists (including myself :)) would be something like: "Does quantum entanglement cause any phenomena we observe in daily life?". In general physicists do not like questions with a logically inconsistent premise, which your original question has (even though you did not intend this), but we like to give examples where subtle physics arises unexpectedly in daily life. Maybe this is not what you intended, in which case I'm sorry for putting words in your mouth.

Comment: @Andrew: I appreciate the suggestion but this is a different question which has already been asked. I was not looking for examples of entanglement in nature per se. I was more looking for laws of physics falling apart because of the absence of entanglement, like possibly instabilities in astrophysics, end of life, etc.

Comment: If there were no number 8, how would arithmetic change?

Comment: @WillO Comments should be helpful or ask for clarification from the OP. Additionally the role 8 plays in arithmetic and entanglement in quantum theory are not analogous. Maybe it would be better to post more helpful comments.

Comment: @Biophysicist:  The analogy is that the existence of entanglement is every bit as unavoidable a consequence of the structure of quantum mechanics as the existence of the number 8 is an unavoidable consequence of the structure of arithmetic.  In my experience with students, comments like this sometimes (and more often than rarely) trigger useful "Aha!" moments.  I am happy to acknowledge that your experience might be different.

Comment: @WillO: To answer your remark and methodology: sorry, no "Aha!" moment here. The analogy is way too limited to be helpful. 8 is not a foundation of arithmetic. It is a consequence of an otherwise continuous system of representation. Saying entanglement is like number 8 **could** make it avoidable. I can avoid every apple larger than 8 cm, or every cable cheaper than 8 euros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quantum mechanics is a theory which is (1) linear and (2) allows to describe composite systems (consisting of more than one object/part/constituent). These two properties given immediately rise to the notion of entanglement. There is no quantum mechanics without entanglement, unless you use it to describe only single objects (whatever this even *means* - well, maybe a single electron in an external potential) and nothing else. You cannot take entanglement out of quantum mechanics, and thus, asking for a world which has quantum mechanics but no entanglement makes no sense.

To put it differently, the only quantum mechanics without entanglement is single-particle quantum mechanics. This has some interest - you can describe quantum cryptography, band theory, the hydrogen atom, and a few other things - but in essence, you have to impose that quantum mechanics does not apply any more once you have two particles which interact, which would be a rather artificial cutoff and, more importantly, make quantum mechanics a theory with rather limited applicability.

Comment: Are you saying that entanglement happens in every other natural phenomena when they are described by a linear theory allowing composite systems? Your answer may make sense to a physicist only.

Comment: Any linear theory describing composition of systems via a tensor product will exhibit entanglement. Mathematically, an entangled state is one that cannot be written as a product of two separate states belonging to different tensor product factors.

Comment: Of course students of physics are physicists. And I think my answer makes it clear that entanglement is intimately linked to the very structure of quantum mechanics, and quantum mechanics without entanglement just doesn't make sense. Of course, if you want to know in detail why, you have to be willing to learn some quantum mechanics.

Comment: @QuantumFieldMedalist I'm not even sure the "tensor product" is required as an *extra* condition: If a linear theory works for a system, and it works for another one, and it can describe both systems at the same time if they reside in independent locations, then you automatically get the tensor product structure.

Comment: It is a postulate of quantum mechanics that composite systems are described by tensor products, so I think for a general theory one would need to specify how composition works.

Comment: @QuantumFieldMedalist I agree, but the typical postulates are not necessarily minimalist. My claim is that it can be replaced by a much simpler postulate, namely that if I have two separated systems (e.g. in two labs), I can still describe each of them by a quantum state (one for each), and the description of the experiement in lab 1 unaffected by the presence of the second system + its state. This + linearity necessarily gives tensor products, and I think it is much more fundamental. (Basically, it is the basic tenet of physics, that you can do experiments on isolated systems.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Why not describe a multipartite Hilbert space as a direct sum of the factor subspaces? I think that there could be various ways of composition and it is not so obvious why tensor products are needed. For example, in QFT one does not have a tensor product factorization of Hilbert spaces associated to different regions.

Answer (score -1):

It is dangerous to try and conjure up a world without entanglement, because there would tend to be inconsistencies. However, if one can ignore such inconsistencies, then one thing that I can think of that would be different is that coupling constants would not run, because there would not be Feynman diagrams with loops in them. All such loop diagrams imply entanglement. If there is no running coupling, then QCD would not have a confinement scale. In other words, protons and neutrons would leak color charge. The implication is that the world would look very different and we would probably not be here.